# Not able to install Elasticsearch as different user

Tags: hadoop, elasticsearch, solr, lucene, full-text-search

I have downloaded elasticsearch rpm 2.3.1 on centos machine. I want to install it as other then elasticsearch user. By default ES_USER is set as elasticsearch. Can someone please help me if we can override ES_USER with other user while installing rpm or how to reset elasticsearch default username?

Thanks

Comment: Why is this tagged with hadoop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the user running Elasticsearch via the `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` file under the `ES_USER` environment variable.

Comment: thank you for answer. 

If I am installing elasticsearch rpm and by default it creates username and group as "elasticsearch". I dont want to create those username and group name. I want different name and group.

Could you please let me know if we can do this while installing elasticesearch rpm?

Comment: I don't think you can control that part when you install Elasticsearch but only afterwards by manually creating a user that will be used for the elasticsearch process.

Comment: I have the same problem and I tried to set the **ES_USER** and **ES_GROUP** in the `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch` and also in the `/etc/init.d/elasticsearch`. Elasticsearch still creates the file with user and group _elasticsearch_.